# QML Positioning

Tags: qt, qml, positioning

I am using QML to place a boy next to rectangle shape or above the rectangle shape.
but there are problems that I can't solve.
here is the output when placing the boy next to the rectangle shape:
[image: next]
here is the output when placing the boy above the shape:
[image: above]

Here is my code:

```
Rectangle {
            id: backgroundScreen
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            state: "rightPosition"
            width: 1200
            height: 400
            y: 120
            color: "#55333333"
            visible: true
            radius: 5

            Image {
                id: boy
                anchors.left: undefined
                anchors.bottom: undefined
                anchors.top: undefined
                anchors.right: undefined
            }

            Image {
                id: backSide
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }

           states: [
               State {
                   name: "rightPosition"
                   when: items.checkState == "RIGHT"
                   AnchorChanges {
                       target: boy
                       anchors.verticalCenter: backSide.verticalCenter
                       anchors.left: backSide.right //correct position
                       anchors.bottom: undefined
                       anchors.top: undefined
                       anchors.right: undefined
                   }
                   PropertyChanges {
                       target: boy
                       anchors.leftMargin: 3
                       anchors.rightMargin: 3
                       anchors.topMargin: 3
                       anchors.bottomMargin: 3
                   }
               },
               State {
                   name: "abovePosition"
                   when: items.checkState == "ABOVE"
                   AnchorChanges {
                       target: boy
                       anchors.bottom: backSide.top
                       anchors.horizontalCenter: backSide.horizontalCenter
                       anchors.top: undefined
                       anchors.left: undefined
                       anchors.right: undefined
                   }
                   PropertyChanges {
                       target: boy
                       anchors.leftMargin: 3
                       anchors.rightMargin: 3
                       anchors.topMargin: 3
                       anchors.bottomMargin: 3
                   }
               }
            ]
```

Comment: Can you state what is the problem? The desired position is not clear from the question

Comment: why are you anchoring undefined everywhere?

Comment: @Amfasis  The desired position is ( boy is at the right of the rectangle shape) and also when clicking on it The desired position will be ( boy is above the rectangle shape).

Comment: @Mola, probably to be sure it is not anchored to anything, basically to reset it. It's quite useless here, but I don't think it is the problem here

Comment: @MariamFahmy I see two rectangles, so that's why I'm asking which one. The small teal one or the big semi-transparent?

Comment: @Amfasis, the small one, the big one is just a background

Comment: Is this the idea you're after? https://gist.github.com/amfasis/0a345b80335343cb1008908401bac90a If so, I suspect you have some weirdness with the Images (which you do not show, so we can't know)

Comment: @Amfasis, yes this what I means, but it didn't work with me.

Comment: I suggest you try to solve step by step. Otherwise, show more of your code and the images, in a way other can reproduce it

Comment: From your code, you have 1 rectangle and 2 children images . But on the screenshot, I don't see the 2nd image (the one with the id "backSide"). Also, it is always nice to play with ```clip: true``` , ```clip: false``` on you parent object, to see if your children do (not) oversize their parent.